# Facebook: How to get username by access_token?

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I know it's a pretty weird question, but I wanna use an access_token which  comes from no where to get **who** use **which** facebook_app created this access_token.  just like access token debugger do.

[Facebook Access Token Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/)

why I gonna do that?
my website could sign up with and only with facebook, but now I got attacked by sending fake user_id and user_name to my api,
so I wanna add an input **key** which is **access_token** I got from front-end to my api, send it with **user_name** and **user_id** to server,
then decode this access_token or somehow magic way to get **user_name** from this access_token. 
Final, compare these two **user_name** come from front-end and from access_token, then I could know if this user is fake or not.

what a long way to go, but I have no idea how to determine the request is comes from a human or a robot : (

Comment: you can´t get the username anymore, only use the id to identify users

Comment: that's too bad :(  I thought I could get username like facebook debugger do.  the id and username send from robot is exactly matched, but I'm pretty sure they didn't sign up my website : (

Comment: Just send the access token to the server, and no additional stuff that could easily be faked. Use that access token on the server side to make an API call and request the user’s details.

Comment: but my app only have basic permissions, if a guy has an app which also has basic permissions, he/she can get basic permissions' access_token by his/her own app, then use that access_token as a key to call my app, I tried that way, and it works

Comment: I'm super surprised that the access_token from my app could get user_info from the guy who never use my app |||